# I need to know some information about _v_sched_sys view in netezza

Tags: view, netezza

There is no information available about _v_sched_sys view in netezza. This has been checked when there are many queries running on the system . I have checked in the system admin guide the parameter host.sysVtUpdateInterval (The number of seconds between updates of the _vt_sched_sys virtual table.) has the value of 600 .

But still after 600 seconds I am not able to see any information from the view .

So, if will be great if someone please let me know some information about this view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can view info from this view.

Enable virtual table _vt_sched_sys using the cliqa command: cliqa -vt _vt_sched_sys on
After that every 10 mins _vt_sched_sys will be updated
View _v_sched_sys is based on _vt_sched_sys. That's why above steps.